# How can I get parameter and path for HTTP Request in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

Iam very fresher in JMETER Testing(today just started) and using j2me application for mob  app.How can I use parameters,path from this link for HTTP Request

app2.new.com:8080/NewSwitch/Download?entity_type=bank&new_id=4&branch_id=99
&agent_id=1212&link_branch=&

Thanks 
Nami

Comment: See here similar question and answer:
http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7073/how-to-build-a-test-for-iterative-http-requests-using-jmeter/7075

Answer (score 0):

well, let's start by breaking down your link:

app2.new.com:8080/NewSwitch/Download?entity_type=bank&new_id=4&branch_id=99 &agent_id=1212&link_branch=&

This is an HTTP query:

```
    app2.new.com        This is the site
    8080                This is the port
    /NewSwitch/Download This is the path
    entity_type=bank    These are 5 parameters, each with name and value:
    new_id=4              insert 5 lines into the parameter table and fill them in.
    branch_id=99
    agent_id=1212
    link_branch=
```